# Performance: Class Based Views VS Function Based Views

Tags: python, django

I'm curious about this, from a performance point of view only, how do their differ considering the proper use?

Comment: I think most of the benefits of class-based views are with orgenizing your code, reducing repetition and making it more reusable (mixin techniques and such). I believe the performance differences are minimal or non-existent. That's just my opinion, I have no authority to know that for a fact. So a comment, not an answer

Comment: In Python, the most expensive operation is function call. CBVs do a LOT of function calls. That being said, the application layer is rarely the bottleneck of the system.

Comment: @Thomas, yes I imagined this situation but actually I would like to know if someone have profiled this. What is price of CBV's features in overall performance. Maybe that could be argument for a hybrid approach, I mean, use CBV only when it's necessary maybe.

Comment: Also, when there is a problem, whether it is performance related or otherwise, class-based views can be more difficult to debug. Realize that is a generalization and may not be true in all cases. In the end, I just find that function based views map well to the the HTTP request/response cycle...args (request) in, return (response) out.

Answer (score 1):

They don't differ in performance at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about this?

Comment: It is not of a practical importance that there are few more function calls (+instance creation) during request processing. You are never going to create tons of class-based-views in a loop because they are what they are - views. Constant tiny performance hit is _nothing_. In anything web-related, the bottleneck is always data access. That being said, you should try to avoid iterating over querysets in views and doing some logic on every item - let db do that and just fetch the results. If you do such a thing, then you really can encounter python part itself being slow and memory consuming.